# How to select config in `flask db migrate`

Tags: flask-migrate

I have both development db and production db connection strings in my .env.

```
LOCAL_DB_STRING="local_db"
DB_STRING="production_db"
LOCAL_APP_STATE="development"
```

When running app, the correct one is loaded using config.py:

```
class Config(object):
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get("DB_STRING")

    APP_STATE = os.environ.get("APP_STATE")


class DevConfig(Config):
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get("LOCAL_DB_STRING")
    APP_STATE = os.environ.get("LOCAL_APP_STATE")
```

and then in `__init__.py` `create_app()`

```
application.config.from_object(configs[config_name])
```

How can I use `flask-migrate` similar way - choosing which db (dev/prod) it uses for its commands?

Thanks for help!

SOLVED: I found out it was my mistake - I was getting APP_STATE from APP_STATE variable, but in my .env file there was LOCAL_APP_STATE. So `flask db` didn't get right environment.

Comment: How do you set the `config_name` argument when you run the server? Use the same method for the `flask db` commands.

Comment: I'm getting it from .env automatically.
Using `pipenv run flask run` for running locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was mistake in my `.env` file - using `LOCAL_APP_STATE` instead of `APP_STATE`, which made `flask db` run default config.